# How to reuse a .Net assembly from a pure C application

Tags: .net, c++, c, interop

I have a legacy application written in C , and i would like to gradually move some code to c#. But before being able to rewrite everything i will need to have just few components writen in c# first that are going to be used from C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your **C#** class is a static class. You need to create an interop layer in **C++/CLI** before you can use it in pure **C**. Create a **C++/CLI** class to wrap your **C#** class. Once that is done use the export function to export the specific **C** functions. C++/CLI will manage the interop on your behalf. The rule of thumb is if you class/function has any CLI it WILL BE CLI. So your extern functions should only return native datatypes.

```
extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int MyFunc(long parm1);
```

Here is an article to help you get started. It converts **C++** to **C#** but the process is reversed in your case. [**CodeProject**](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/marshalCPPclass.aspx) Unfortunately there is no convenient reverse **PInvoke** for pure **C**.

Unfortunately I have never gone from **C#** to **C**. It sounds like an interesting project. Good luck!

Ok If you have not figured it out yet i have a quick sample for you.

**C# CSLibrary.Math.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace CSLibrary
{
    static public class Math
    {
        static public int Add(int a, int b)
        {
            int c = a + b;
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

**Cpp/C++ Project CPPCLibrary.h** (Compiled with C++/CLI Option with project dependencies)

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) int MathAdd(int a, int b)
{
    return CSLibrary::Math::Add(a, b);
}
```

**C Project CTest.c** (Compiled as C Code)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "../Debug/CPPCLILibrary.lib") 

extern __declspec( dllimport ) int MathAdd(int a, int b);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int answer = MathAdd(10, 32);
    _tprintf(_T("%d\n"), answer);
    return 0;
}
```

All files are in the same solution but different projects. I have confirmed this has worked. I hope this helps anyone who comes across it.

Cheers!

Comment: If I get some time I would like to create a small demo. This sounds fun.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is pure C, you might be able to put it into a visual C++ assembly project without too much difficulty. From there, you would have access to a regular .net api.